# Constructor and Methods are not giving output

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I am writing a code on computerization of health records and making a program. But when i ran it ,it only gives the output:-

The total years of that person is 21613

BMI values
Under weight:   less than 18.5
 normal:    between 18.5 and 24.9
Overweight: between 25 and 29.9
Obese:  30 or greater
Enter the value of Height and Weight

but all my other methods are not running and constructor as well, please just give me the idea how to solve this? 
My program is :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Starter{

    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private String Gender;
    private int DOB;
    private int MOB;
    private int YOB;
    private double Height;  //inches
    private double Weight;  //KG.
    String greeting=FirstName+LastName+Gender;
    double BMI1;    
    public Starter(){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter all the required data");
        FirstName=input.nextLine();
        LastName=input.nextLine();
        Gender=input.nextLine();
        DOB=input.nextInt();
        MOB=input.nextInt();
        YOB=input.nextInt();
    }





     public void setFirstName(String Fname){
           FirstName=Fname;

          }
       public void setLastName(String Lname){
           LastName=Lname;
       }
       public void setGender(String G){
           Gender=G;
           }
       public void setBirth(int Day,int Month,int Year){
           DOB=Day;
           MOB=Month;
           YOB=Year;


       }
       public String getFirstName(){
           return FirstName;
       }
       public String getLastName(){
           return LastName;
       }
       public String getGender(){
           return Gender;
       }
       public int getDOB()
       {
        return DOB;
    }
       public int getMOB(){
           return MOB;

       }
       public int getYOB(){
           return YOB;
        }
       public void BMI1(){
           System.out.println("Enter the value of Height and Weight");
           Scanner input1=new Scanner(System.in);
           Height=input1.nextFloat();
           Weight=input1.nextFloat();
            BMI1=Weight/(Height*Height);
            System.out.println("The BMI value is :\t"+BMI1);
       }
      public  void getYears(){
          int TotalYear=2014-YOB;
          int TotalMonth=12-MOB;
          int TotalDay=31-DOB;
          System.out.printf("The total years of that person is %d-%d-%d",TotalYear,TotalMonth,TotalDay);
          System.out.println("\n");
       }
      public    void BMI(){
            System.out.println("BMI values");
            System.out.println("Under weight:\tless than 18.5\n normal:\tbetween 18.5 and 24.9\nOverweight:\tbetween 25 and 29.9\nObese:\t30 or greater");
        }      
}





public class HeartRates {

public static void main(String[] args) {

       Starter getvalues2=new Starter();
       getvalues2.setFirstName("Sachin");
       getvalues2.setLastName("Godara");
       getvalues2.setGender("Male");
       getvalues2.setBirth(18,6,1993);
       getvalues2.getFirstName();
       getvalues2.getLastName();
       getvalues2.getGender();
       getvalues2.getDOB();
       getvalues2.getMOB();
       getvalues2.getYOB();
       getvalues2.getYears();
       getvalues2.BMI();
       getvalues2.BMI1();




        }


}
```

**MY OUTPUT SHOULD BE :-**

```
Enter all the required data
sam 
godara
male
18
6
1993
The total years of that person is 21-6-13

BMI values
Under weight:   less than 18.5
 normal:    between 18.5 and 24.9
Overweight: between 25 and 29.9
Obese:  30 or greater
Enter the value of Height and Weight
 2
78
The BMI value is :  19.5
Sachin 
godara
male
1861993
```

Comment: Your naming is very confusing, please follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: But i don't get it sir , why naming is so important,  at-least my whole program should run. but why it is not running?

Comment: The compiler doesn't care about naming, we do. It's for readability.

Comment: Then why my constructor and other methods are not running?

Comment: I corrected the error in constructor, but my other methods are not running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a constructor. If this :

```
void starter(){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter all the required data");
    FirstName=input.nextLine();
    LastName=input.nextLine();
    Gender=input.nextLine();
    DOB=input.nextInt();
    MOB=input.nextInt();
    YOB=input.nextInt();
}
```

is meant as a constructor then its wrong. Even though a constructor is a void method, it is not declared like that. Change it to:

```
public Starter(){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter all the required data");
    FirstName=input.nextLine();
    LastName=input.nextLine();
    Gender=input.nextLine();
    DOB=input.nextInt();
    MOB=input.nextInt();
    YOB=input.nextInt();
}
```

**Update 1**

These methods:

```
getvalues2.getFirstName();
getvalues2.getLastName();
getvalues2.getGender();
getvalues2.getDOB();
getvalues2.getMOB();
getvalues2.getYOB();
getvalues2.getYears();
```

return a value. That doesn't mean they have to print it..

Try

```
system.out.println(getvalues2.getFirstName());
system.out.println(getvalues2.getLastName());
....//etc
```

**Update 2**

> also why it is giving The total years of that person is 21613 in
>   output

This is happening because of this:

```
System.out.printf("The total years of that person is %d%d%d",TotalYear,TotalMonth,TotalDay);
```

`%d%d%d` means that `printf` expects 3 `ints` as arguements and will place then next to each other.

I think this will make more sense to you:

```
`%d%d%d` output `123`
`%d %d %d` output `1 2 3`
`%d-%d-%d` output `1-2-3`
```

So you can change it appropriatelly.

**Update 3**

```
 public void BMI1(){
     System.out.println("Enter the value of Height and Weight");
     Scanner input1=new Scanner(System.in);
     Height=input1.nextFloat();
     Weight=input1.nextFloat();
     BMI1=Weight/(Height*Height);
     System.out.println("The BMI value is :\t"+BMI1);
 }
```

From your comment i am assuming that your porgramm is hanging here. This method is expecting you to input 2 `float`s before printing out something. So if you don't enter something it won't get the to the `System.out.println("The BMI value is :\t"+BMI1);`

Comment: i erase the void but after that it showing an error in eclipse that return type for method is missing.

Comment: thats because Java is case sensitive and Eclipse this that you have created a method and its missing the return type. You constructor has to be the exact same name as your class. So `public Starter()` instead of `starter`

Comment: Yes i also use the public but again it showing same error . But if i remove my Constructor part then why my other methods are not running except BMI and BMI1.

Comment: Ok i used your suggestion and my constructor is running but my other methods are not?

Comment: Please define "how" they are not running? How do you know they are not running? What's the expected output and what do you get?

Comment: basically now my output is Enter all the required data
sachin
godara
male
18
6
1993
The total years of that person is 21613

BMI values
Under weight: less than 18.5
 normal: between 18.5 and 24.9
Overweight: between 25 and 29.9
Obese: 30 or greater
Enter the value of Height and Weight
only constructor and BMI and BMI1 are running but my set and get methods are not giving any output. And also why it is giving             The total years of that person is 21613 in output.

Comment: yes you are right sir i used your update 2 but why my other methods are not printing the values when i use your update one.

Comment: Does your program print anything at all?

Comment: Now the output is :-   Enter all the required data
jon
martin
male
18
6
1993
The total years of that person is 21-6-13

BMI values
Under weight: less than 18.5
 normal: between 18.5 and 24.9
Overweight: between 25 and 29.9
Obese: 30 or greater
Enter the value of Height and Weight
2
78
The BMI value is : 19.5

Comment: can you please update your answer with what the expected output is and what are you getting? I cannot be reading the comments and you should have put that in your question in first place

Comment: i update my program with output, all the things right but only Sachin, godara,male, 1861993 are not print ,also i used your update 1

Comment: check update 3. Are you aware that the program is waiting input from you?

Comment: I checked it.but no solution i just only want to know that why my getfirstname and other methods are not printing anything?

Comment: Try to remove everything in the constructor and leave only this: `System.out.println("Enter all the required data");`

Comment: Tried but no solution.

Answer (score 1):

If this method is supposed to be the constructor :

```
void starter(){
```

It should be :

```
public Starter(){
```

Otherwise, it's just a regular class method, and won't be executed when you call `new Starter()`.

A constructor doesn't have a return type, and Java is case sensitive.

EDIT :

Change :

```
System.out.printf("The total years of that person is %d%d%d",TotalYear,TotalMonth,TotalDay);
```

to :

```
System.out.printf("The total years of that person is %d %d %d",TotalYear,TotalMonth,TotalDay);
```

In order to make the output more readable.

Comment: Ok i used your suggestion and my constructor is running but my other methods are not?  Why and also why it is giving the output:- The total years of that person is 21613.

Comment: @SachinGodara Which methods are not running? How do you know they are not running? Not all your methods print output.

Comment: basically now my output is Enter all the required data
sachin
godara
male
18
6
1993
The total years of that person is 21613

BMI values
Under weight: less than 18.5
 normal: between 18.5 and 24.9
Overweight: between 25 and 29.9
Obese: 30 or greater
Enter the value of Height and Weight
only constructor and BMI and BMI1 are running but my set and get methods are not giving any output.

Comment: @SachinGodara Your methods are running, but some of them don't print any output to System.out. This line - `The total years of that person is 21613` will be clearer if you add spaces (see edited answer).

Comment: yes i used it ,but about the methods i also use   system.out.println(getvalues2.getFirstName());
system.out.println(getvalues2.getLastName()); //etc but no output